# Execution failed for task ':react-native-vision-camera:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: react-native, react-native-vision-camera

I have a react-native project which I've just upgraded to version 0.73 (https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.72.7&to=0.73.0).

The project was already making use of react-native-vision-camera 3.6.10 for a feature that reads barcodes.

However, when I try to build the Android apk I get the error:

```
> Task :react-native-vision-camera:compileDebugKotlin
e: file:///Users/user/Documents/project/node_modules/react-native-vision-camera/android/src/main/java/com/mrousavy/camera/CameraDevicesManager.kt:74:3 'hasConstants' overrides nothing
e: file:///Users/user/Documents/project/node_modules/react-native-vision-camera/android/src/main/java/com/mrousavy/camera/frameprocessor/VisionCameraProxy.kt:38:58 Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type JavaScriptContextHolder?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-vision-camera:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details
```

I've tried downgrading the kotlin version 1.8.0, to 1.6.20 and 1.7.21, as set in react-native-vision-camera and also mentioned in some comments:
https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/1012#issuecomment-1665622677

But it didn't make it... The errors get even worse...
Any ideas how I could fix this? Or how could I find the proper kotlin version?

Comment: Upgrading to react-native-vision-camera 3.6.14 reduced the errors to only one:
    e: file:///Users/user/Documents/project/node_modules/react-native-vision-camera/android/src/main/java/com/mrousavy/camera/CameraDevicesManager.kt:74:3 'hasConstants' overrides nothing

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually an answer, but having suffered through this same issue... the reason I stayed at 0.72.x is because that's what the react-native-vision-camera demo app is using.  Not sure if support goes beyond that point yet.

Comment: Thanks for the comment... react-native-vision-camera just added a bug fix for this as well... so now it works with 0.73.x

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/2263

the error

```
'hasConstants' overrides nothing
```

solution https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/2263#issuecomment-1846827956

> It seems this error emerged following the removal of the hasConstants method in RN, a change that was merged in version, surprise surprise, 0.73. facebook/react-native@bbc3657:

```
- public boolean hasConstants() {
-   return false;
- }
```

Simply removing the hasConstants() method resolves the problem:
package/android/src/main/java/com/mrousavy/camera/CameraDevicesManager.kt:

```
- override fun hasConstants(): Boolean = true
```

ISSUE: https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/2184
PR: https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/pull/2264